# Downloading a Windows 8.1 .iso from MSDN with an OEM key

Tags: windows, iso-image

I have a computer with Windows 8.1 preinstalled. I'd like to obtain an .iso so as to be able to reinstall it in case something happens.

I know about the solution which uses the [upgrade](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only) method but it's not very handy. Windows 7 in VirtualBox has some features turned off and besides, I'd have to give it half of my whole RAM. I'd like to have the real iso, for the setup recognize to recognize the key embedded in UEFI.

I'd like to download directly from MSDN but I can't find a way to activate a subscription from an OEM key.

Is there any way I could get the .iso directly from the MS servers without tinkering with virtual machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download it from here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=510815

<sub>*Note that this is the actual download link (downloads when you click on it), rather than a resource page containing a download link.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows 8.1 preinstalled, that means it is OEM PC, usually it come with recovery partition or recovery disc.

Besides, Windows 8.1 has [build-in refresh function](http://windows.microsoft.com/zh-HK/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc) which revert your PC to a clean state.

However, you can't download it directly from MSDN unless you are MS partner company. If you really want a Win8.1 iso, the only way is download from Google or borrow from friends. MS is vailding the CD-KEY only, it doesn't matter which media you are  use to install the Windows.

Comment: And what if I make the installation unbootable or delete Windows altogether?

Comment: For OEM recovery, it is on hidden partition or a separated disc. It is better to provide your PC model for further checking.

Comment: I have an Asus T200TA. I'd rather spare the space for a Linux than waste it for a recovery partition

Comment: For asus computer, you can use ASUS Backtracker to backup the recovery partition
http://www.asus.com/2in1-PCs/ASUS_Transformer_Book_T200TA/HelpDesk_Download/

Expand `Utilities` to download, however, it is not recommended to mess with the recovery partition, you may get in to trouble later.